# Программа после post запроса возвращает весь код страницы

Tags: python, html, браузер

Сейчас я учу requests  и хочу попробовать создать простой чекер origin.
Вот пример того что у меня есть.

```
    import requests

file=open('dat.txt').read().split('\n')

for account in file:
    logn=account.split(':')[0]
    passw=account.split(':')[1]
    result=requests.post("https://signin.ea.com/p/originX/login?execution=e151626130s1&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fdisplay%3DoriginXWeb%252Flogin%26response_type%3Dcode%26release_type%3Dprod%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.origin.com%252Fviews%252Flogin.html%26locale%3Dru_RU%26client_id%3DORIGIN_SPA_ID",data={'email':'logn','password':'passw'}).text
    print(str(result))
```

Но мой код возвращает мне весь html код страницы.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>ВОЙТИ</title>
    <meta name="title" content="ВОЙТИ"/>
    <meta name="description" content="ВОЙТИ"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/p/favicon.ico"/>
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <meta name="lc" content="ru_RU"/>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/ui/core/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.v_1618545690.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/ui/core/js/jquery.origin-ux-elements-new.v_1618545690-min.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/ui/core/js/jquery.origin-layout.v_1618545690-min.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/js/jquery.originX-pc-common.v_1618545688-min.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/js/sha.v_1618545688-min.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/js/jquery.originX-pc-login.v_1618545688-min.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>

        <script src='https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js?hl=ru'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //remove google recaptcha errors if verified successfully
    var resetGoogleRecaptcha = function(){
        $("#google-captcha-container").find(".otkinput-errormsg").removeClass('otkform-group-haserror');
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.login({
            'gCaptchaEnabled':true,
            'source':"WEB",
            'ipCountry': 'RU',
            'phoneNumber': '',
            'contextPath' : "https://signin.ea.com:443/p",
            'selectedCountry': '',
            'isPhoneNumberLogin' :false,
            'isIncompletePhone' :true,
            'isFromAccountLink' :false,
            'isPhoneNumberChecked' :false
                    });
        $('#recaptcha_response_field').width('250px');
        $(document.body).addClass("unselectable");
    });
    window.onload =function(e) {
        if ($("#email").val()) {
            $("#password").focus();
        } else{
            $("#email").focus();
        }
    };
</script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/pin/js/jquery.pin.v_1618545688-min.js" onerror="window.location='/p/originX/offline?locale=ru_RU&theme=theme'"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.fn.pin({
                pinRestUrl: "https://pin-river.data.ea.com/pinEvents",
                pinRestHeaders: {
                    'x-ea-game-id-type': 'client',
                    'x-ea-game-id': 'server_nucleus',
                    'x-ea-taxv': '2.0',
                    'x-ea-env': 'prod'
                },
                pinRestMessage: {
                    curStep: "originX/login",
                    prevStep: "originX/login-0",
                    stepNum: "1",
                    sessionId: "RlMxOjMuMDoyLjA6SlBkV3JScXVrR0hFN3dqNTRyVVJoeVBKOnBuaTR0",
                    titleId: "196775",
                    titleIdType: "projectid",
                    category: "originX/login",
                    version: "0.5-prod",
                    environment: "prod",
                    platform: "unknown"
                },
                pathRestMessage: {
                    type: "funnel"
                }
            });
            $.fn.pin.helpers.postPathMessageOnLoad();
        });
    </script>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/css/otk.v_1618545688-min.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/css/originX-pc-common.v_1618545688-min.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/css/originX-pc-login.v_1618545688-min.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/resource_signin_ea_com/550.0.210416.011.5a58bad/p/statics/originX/css/originX-pc-login_ru.v_1618545688-min.css"/>

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','originXAnalytics');
    originXAnalytics('create', 'UA-38277543-5', '.ea.com');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
    <!-- Tealium -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var utag_data = {
            region: "EMEA",
            locale : "ru_RU",
            country : "RU",
            language : "ru",
            userid : "",
            user_status : "",
            referring_site : "",
            page_name : "https://signin.ea.com/p/originX/login"
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (a, b, c, d) {
            a = '//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/ea/originx/prod/utag.js';
            b = document;
            c = 'script';
            d = b.createElement(c);
            d.src = a;
            d.type = 'text/java' + c;
            d.async = true;
            a = b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];
            a.parentNode.insertBefore(d, a);
        })();
    </script>
    <!-- End of tealium -->
</head>
<body>


<div class="form-container">

<div class="otknotice-stripe otknotice-active " id=originXBannerBox>
    <div class="otknotice-stripe-message">
        <span class="otkicon otkicon-warning"></span>
        <span class="otkc otkc-small">
                                <strong>
                </strong>
                        </span>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="logViews" class="views">
        <!-- navigation -->
<nav class="otknavbar" role="navigation">
    <ul class="otknav otknav-pills">
            <li class="otkpill otkpill-active">
                <a id="loginNav" style="display: block;" href="./login?fid=RlMxOjMuMDoyLjA6SlBkV3JScXVrR0hFN3dqNTRyVVJoeVBKOnBuaTR0&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fdisplay%3DoriginXWeb%252Flogin%26response_type%3Dcode%26release_type%3Dprod%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.origin.com%252Fviews%252Flogin.html%26locale%3Dru_RU%26client_id%3DORIGIN_SPA_ID">ВОЙТИ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="otkpill ">
                <a id="createNav" style="display: block;" href="./create?fid=RlMxOjMuMDoyLjA6SlBkV3JScXVrR0hFN3dqNTRyVVJoeVBKOnBuaTR0&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fdisplay%3DoriginXWeb%252Flogin%26response_type%3Dcode%26release_type%3Dprod%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.origin.com%252Fviews%252Flogin.html%26locale%3Dru_RU%26client_id%3DORIGIN_SPA_ID">Создать учетную запись</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

        <!-- views -->
        <section id="loginBase">
            <form id="back-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="back" id="_eventId"/>
                <a style="display: none;" id="back" href="#" class="back-btn otktitle otktitle-5 otktitle-5-caps"><i
                        class="otkicon otkicon-leftarrowcircle"></i>Назад</a>
                <a style="display: none;" id="back-to-main-sign-in" href="#" class="back-btn otktitle otktitle-5 otktitle-5-caps"><i
                        class="otkicon otkicon-leftarrowcircle"></i>BACK TO MAIN SIGN IN</a>
            </form>

            <div class="panel" id="login-with-OriginId-or-Email-panel" style="display: block">
                    <h1 id="loginWithOriginIDTitle"
```

Answer (score 1):

Так вы в явном виде берёте именно `.text` от результата запроса:

```
result=requests.post(...).text
```

Берите `.headers` вместо `.text` или что вам там нужно получить.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Это улучшило ситуацию